# sql server conditional where

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, where-clause

```
select * from table where category=@categoryid
```

I'm not sure how easy is this but I couldn't get my head around it. I want to be able to change where clause on above query so that if use 0 instead of 1-2-3 or 4 as @categoryid it would select all categories. i don't have any category with 0 in database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple.

```
select * from table where (category=@categoryid) OR (@categoryid = 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

This should probably be divided into 2 separate queries unless you actually want the same execution plan of a full clustered index scan to be used both in the case that `@categoryid=0` and `@categoryid<>0`

By dividing into 2 separate queries you will potentially allow the ones where `@categoryid` is not zero to be satisfied by an index seek rather than the full scan.

If the table is small or `@categoryid` is not very selective it might not be an issue however.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it to NULL when you want to select all categories an just modify select like this

```
select * from table where category= ISNULL( @categoryid, category )
```

Comment: Not exactly answers the question but it's cleaner than the Matt Gibson's approach but requires a couple of modifications on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where 
category BETWEEN @mincategoryid AND @maxcategoryid
```

Min and max will one of

- both be 1 (or 2 or 3 or 4)
- respectively 0 and a high number

This will use an index too..

Comment: @KM: sounds like a non-nullable column though

Answer (score -2):

This is SQL not PL/SQL.
You need to test the value before sending the request you can not ask to SQL test it for you.

Comment: I downvoted you, because I couldn't understand your argument.

Comment: Fair enough, seems like i spoke over my head this time :D